# Distributed storage for Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Official guide says:

> If using a path on the local filesystem, the file must also be
>   accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to
>   all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system.

Does Spark need some sort of distributed file system for shuffle or whatever? Or can I just copy input across all nodes and don't bother with NFS, HDFS etc?

Comment: If you can copy all your data across all nodes, why do you need Spark at all? It might be faster and easier to process data locally on one computer. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark does not depend on a distirbuted file system for shuffle. Unlike traditional map reduce, Spark doesn't need to write to HDFS (or similar) system, instead Spark achieves resiliency by tracking the lineage of the data and using that in the event of node failure by re-computing any data which was on that node.

Comment: So all data transfers between executors are performed only using network and without distributed storage?

Comment: Between executors yes